# WPF Bind TextBlock to Specific Item of List in own ViewModel

Tags: c#, wpf, xaml, data-binding, binding

im new to WPF and ran into a problem when trying to bind multiple TextBlocks to the attributes of my "ItemViewModel"-List.

The HomeView.xaml is a User Control, thats shown on the MainWindow.
I made my own HomeViewModel.cs where all the data is, so I dont use the HomeView.xaml.cs and havent changed anything in that code.

My goal is, that whenever the value of "_items[i]._weight", or "_items[i]._count" in "HomeViewModel.cs" is changed, the bound TextBlock or TextBox in "HomeView.xaml" will get the new value.

Also, how do I tell "item1WeightTBx" for example, that its bound to "_items[**0**]._weight" and not  "_items[**3**]._weight"?

So far the "HomeView.xaml" keeps looking for the Data in "HomeView" and not in "HomeViewModel".

Let me know if you need more code or information :)

Thank you in advance!

**HomeView.xaml** (User Control)

```
<UserControl x:Class="Project.MVVM.View.HomeView"
             xmlns="http://schemas.microsoft.com/winfx/2006/xaml/presentation"
             xmlns:x="http://schemas.microsoft.com/winfx/2006/xaml"
             xmlns:mc="http://schemas.openxmlformats.org/markup-compatibility/2006" 
             xmlns:d="http://schemas.microsoft.com/expression/blend/2008"
             xmlns:viewModel="clr-namespace:Project.MVVM.ViewModel"
             xmlns:local="clr-namespace:Project.MVVM.View"
             mc:Ignorable="d" 
             d:DesignHeight="450" d:DesignWidth="800">

    <Grid>
        <Grid.RowDefinitions>
            <RowDefinition Height="109*"/>
            <RowDefinition Height="156*"/>
            <RowDefinition Height="185*"/>
        </Grid.RowDefinitions>

        <TextBox x:Name="item1WeightTBx"
                 Grid.Row="2"
                 HorizontalAlignment="Left"
                 HorizontalContentAlignment="Center"
                 VerticalContentAlignment="Center"
                 DataContext="{Binding Items}"
                 Text="{Binding _weight}"
                 Height="23" 
                 Margin="51,39,0,0"
                 TextWrapping="Wrap"
                 VerticalAlignment="Top"
                 Width="40"
                 FontSize="14"/>

        <TextBlock x:Name="item1CountTBk"
                   HorizontalAlignment="Left"
                   Grid.Row="2"
                   Height="28"
                   Margin="51,65,0,0"
                   TextWrapping="Wrap"
                   DataContext="{Binding Items}"
                   Text="{Binding _count}"
                   VerticalAlignment="Top"
                   Width="57"
                   FontSize="16"
                   Foreground="#424242"/>

        <TextBox x:Name="item2WeightTBx"
                 Grid.Row="2"
                 HorizontalAlignment="Left"
                 HorizontalContentAlignment="Center"
                 VerticalContentAlignment="Center"
                 DataContext="{Binding Items}"
                 Text="{Binding _weight}"
                 Height="23" 
                 Margin="123,39,0,0"
                 TextWrapping="Wrap"
                 VerticalAlignment="Top"
                 Width="40"
                 FontSize="14"/>

        <TextBlock x:Name="item2CountTBk"
                   HorizontalAlignment="Left"
                   Grid.Row="2"
                   Height="28"
                   Margin="123,65,0,0"
                   TextWrapping="Wrap"
                   DataContext="{Binding Items}"
                   Text="{Binding _count}"
                   VerticalAlignment="Top"
                   Width="57"
                   FontSize="16"
                   Foreground="#424242"/>

                   .
                   .
                   .
```

**HomeViewModel.cs**

```
        public List<ItemViewModel> _items;

        public List<ItemViewModel> Items => _items;


public HomeViewModel(Connection connectionInterface, ShelfComp shelfComp)
        {
            _connectioninterface = connectionInterface;
            _scale = new Scale("0,0;0,0", ShelfWidth);
            _shelfComp = shelfComp;
            

            for (int i = 0; i < shelfComp.ItemList.Count; i++)
            {
                _items.Add(new ItemViewModel(_shelfComp.ItemList[i]));
            } 
        }
```

**ItemViewModel.cs**

```
class ItemViewModel : ObservableObject
    {
        public Item _item;

        public string _name => _item.Name;
        public int _minIndex => _item.MinIndex;
        public int _maxIndex => _item.MaxIndex;
        public double _weight => _item.Weight;
        public int Width => _item.Width;
        public int _count => _item.Count;

        public ItemViewModel(Item item)
        {
            _item = item;
        }
    }
```

**Item.cs**

```
public class Item
    {
        public string Name { get; set; }
        public int MinIndex { get; set; }
        public int MaxIndex { get; set; }
        public double Weight { get; }
        public int Width { get; }
        public int Count { get; set; }


        public Item(string Name, int MinIndex, int Width, double Weight)
        {
            this.Name = Name;
            this.MinIndex = MinIndex;
            this.Width = Width;
            this.MaxIndex = MinIndex + Width;
            this.Weight = Weight;
            Count = 0;
        }

    }
```

**ObservableObject.cs**

```
class ObservableObject : INotifyPropertyChanged
    {
        public event PropertyChangedEventHandler PropertyChanged;

        protected void OnPropertyChanged([CallerMemberName] string propertyName = null)
        {
            PropertyChanged?.Invoke(this, new PropertyChangedEventArgs(propertyName));
        }
    }
```

Comment: You should use full properties with a backing field and every time the property's value is set, you need to call `OnPropertyChanged()`.

Comment: No need to reinvent the wheel by the way, have a look at the `Microsoft.Toolkit.Mvvm` library: https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/windows/communitytoolkit/mvvm/introduction

Answer (score 0):

You must always raise the `INotifyPropetyChanged.PropertyChanged` event in order to update a Binding. Implmenting the interface alone is only half of the story. Every property that should support dynamic binding, must raise the event.

When you compose a type and use member delegation, the instances of the composition members must be `private`. Otherwise the delegation is redundant as the caller can bypass the class API and mutate the instance directly or even overwrite the instance. If you want to hide `Item`, the property *must* be `private`.
Also, never define `public` fields. Currently `ItemViewModel.Item` is a `public` field. It must be `private` and a property.
`public` properties or `public` members in general, must be named using PascalCase. The `_camelCase` notation is used for private fields only.

Same applies to the `HomeViewModel` members:

```cs
public List<ItemViewModel> _items;
public List<ItemViewModel> Items => _items;
```

This is pretty pointless. It's wrong. The backing field MUST be `private` (remember: no `public` fields!). Additionally, since this is a read-only property (it only has a `get()`), the backing field is redundant. You can use a read-only auto property instead:

```cs
// Initialize from constructor
public List<ItemViewModel> Items { get; }
```

Keep in mind that a constructor must execute fast. A longrunning `for` loop must be avoided in the constructor.

To fix your binding issue, make sure that each property on the binding source raises the `INotifyPropetyChanged.PropertyChanged` event:

**ItemViewModel.cs**

```cs
class ItemViewModel : ObservableObject
{
  private Item Item { get; }

  // Repeat this pattern for all remainig properties
  public string Name
  {
     get => Item.Name;
     set
     {
       Item.Name = value;
       OnPropertyChanged();
     }
  }

  public ItemViewModel(Item item)
  {
     Item = item;
  }
}
```